# Is "for you" redundant or unnecessary?

Tags: grammar, meaning, idiomatic-language

Is "for you" redundant or unnecessary?

> This is enough **for you** to attain an expert proficiency
>   in guitar.
>
> This is enough to attain an expert proficiency in
>   guitar.

I don't think the second sentence makes sense, but is there a way to rephrase it so that you can remove "for you" and make sure the sentence still makes sense. The addition of "for you" makes the sentence sound a bit too wordy.

Comment: You could insert a phrase such as **for learners to attain....**. But, as you note, books themselves don't attain proficiency.

Comment: Using 'for you' is a good way to engage the reader, and I don't think it's 'wordy'. There is nothing wrong with the second sentence - it's just not very engaging! Dry, and abstract, without the 'you'. 

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences make sense, and I don't think that the first sentence is too wordy, especially when used in the right context.

If for some reason this were enough for the person you're talking to, but not enough for a different person to attain expert proficiency in guitar, then adding 'for you' would emphasize that fact.

> This is enough for you to attain expert proficiency in guitar, because you've already done so much practicing before now.

In almost any situation where you were talking to a person about their attaining expert proficiency in guitar you could insert 'for you' and it would be appropriate. The second sentence would apply to the person you're talking to but it also means that this would be enough for anybody to achieve expert proficiency in guitar. It's a little impersonal the second way. Depending on the context you might want it to be impersonal or you might not.

Please notice in my answer I haven't used 'an' when talking about expert proficiency. The noun 'proficiency' doesn't have to be a countable noun and I think it shouldn't be in this sentence.